# Loading different logo php file using If statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page template created. When I load my page, it shows the header logo of the mainpage but what I want to achieve is for each custom template created, I want it to only show its own logo.

This is the bit of the header code that calls the logo.php file:

```
<?php get_template_part('parts/logo', 'top') ?>
```

This is what I have tried but not working

```
<?php if ( is_page('custom-page')) {
    get_template_part ('parts/custom-logo', 'top');
} else {
    get_template_part('parts/logo', 'top');
} ?>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have just noticed something not right. I will try and make some changes and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out :). Not sure if this was an error from the owner of the Theme but in the header file, the logo bit was called like this `get_template_part('parts/logo', 'top');` but when I checked the folder **parts** the actual file name was **logo.php** but I was expecting to see **logo-top.php**. That was a bit misleading to me but I might be wrong

So what I simply did was rename my `custom-logo.php` to `custom-logo-top.php` and that fixed the problem.

In fact I also tried this without renaming the file by replacing top with logo and it still worked:

```
<?php if ( is_page('custom-page')) {
    get_template_part ('parts/custom', 'logo');
} else {
    get_template_part('parts/logo', 'top');
} ?>
```